# Declare Selenium's WebDriver as a global variable with SetUp()

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#-4.0, nunit

My current design is as follows: 
Web driver is a part of every SetUp in every Test suite (In this case - Chrome)

```
 public void SetUp()
    {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
    }
```

In order to be able to use a global varible in every test suite, I have created:

```
class Globals
{
    //drivers
    public static IWebDriver driverChrome = new ChromeDriver();

    //ImplicitWait
    public static double ImplicitWaitGlobal = 20;
}
```

Therefore changed my SetUp() to call the global variable:

```
public void SetUp()
    {
        driver = Globals.driverChrome;
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
    }
```

All the above works very well BUT an **additional Chrome window** opens every 
time I run a test (As a result of the creation of a new Chrome driver instance under the Globals class).

The Class looks like this:

```
public class Some_Tests
{
    private IWebDriver driver;
    private IWebElement element;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        driver = new Globals.driverChrome;
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
    }

    [Test]
    [Description("myTest1")]
    public void Test_1()
    {
        Navigate.LogIn_SideBar(Enviroment.Env, Users.user1, driver);
    }

    [Test]
    [Description("myTest2")]
    public void Test_2()
    {
        Navigate.LogIn_SideBar(Enviroment.Env, Users.user1, driver);
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        driver.Close();
        driver.Quit();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to pass the driver in a more 'elegant' way without that happening ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `OneTimeSetup` instead. `Setup` is run once per test method. `OneTimeSetup` is run once before any tests are run. Take a look at [Setup And Teardown Docs](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUp-and-TearDown)

Comment: mm..Does not work for me..I have multiple tests ([Test]) under the class and only the first one passes after I have made the change to [OneTimeSetup]..Am I doing something wrong here...

Comment: The thing is, [Setup] content is required for every test that I'm running..Therefore (I guess) [OnTimeSetup] fails the tests

Comment: @entrup You can use both. Initialize Selenium in `OneTimeSetup` and initialize per test stuff in `Setup`

Comment: Thanks @Mike_Two. I've added the complete Class to clarify things. If I change [SetUp] to [OneTimeSetUp], only the first test will be executed.
 What do you mean by Initialising Selenium with OneTimeSetUp and the tests with SetUp ? Based on what I have here I can use either one not both..Am I'm wrong  ?

Comment: The issue is most probably caused because I'm calling the value for driver under SetUp from Globals (As above) which creates another instance ( Browser Window) which I would like to eliminate.